# sql: sum all previous grouped rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

I have the table below:

```
  date     | shop_id | package_id | quantity
01/01/2017 |   1     |    1       |    1
01/01/2017 |   1     |    2       |    5
01/01/2017 |   2     |    1       |    10
01/01/2017 |   2     |    2       |    4
02/01/2017 |   1     |    1       |    14
02/01/2017 |   1     |    2       |    3
  ....
```

I want to sum the quantities of all the previous records having the same shop and the same package, like the following

```
  date     | shop_id | package_id | sum_quantity
01/01/2017 |   1     |    1       |    1
01/01/2017 |   1     |    2       |    5
01/01/2017 |   2     |    1       |    10
01/01/2017 |   2     |    2       |    4
02/01/2017 |   1     |    1       |    15
02/01/2017 |   1     |    2       |    8

  ....
```

Comment: the DBMS is postgresql

Comment: so you want to Keep all the rows, but get the `sum_quantity` with the same `shop_id` and `package_id` added up for the previous days, correct?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord yes

Answer (score 4):

This is a "running sum" based on shop_id and package_id:

```
select "date", shop_id, package_id,
       sum(quantity) over (partition by shop_id, package_id order by "date") as sum_quantity
from the_table
order by "date";
```

`sum()` is used as a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) (through the `over()` part). The `order by` in the window definition makes this a "running" sum, rather then an "overall" sum.

Online example: http://rextester.com/ZOSK13092